Application of Savitch theorem
We consider a representation of directed graphs that assumes layers in the graph. That is, we denote by $G = \{V_1, V_2, \cdots , V_k; E\}$ the graph whose vertex set is $V =\cup_{i=1}^kV_i$ and $E$ may only contain edges $(u, u')$ such that
$u \in V_i$ and $u' \in V_{i+1}$ (i.e., from a layer $V_i$ to the consecutive layer $V_{i+1}$) for $1 \leq i < k$. Other edges are not allowed (this should not be verified when $G$ is given as input).
Define:
$$L= \{\langle G = {V_1, V_2, \cdots, V_k; E}, s, t\rangle: s \in V_1, t \in V_k \text{ and there is an even number of paths from s to t }\}$$
I want to Prove that $L\in \text{DSPACE}(\log^2(n))$ using the Savitch theorem's proof concepts. My question is how do I start to prove this applying the Savitch theorem?

It may help if you consider that such graphs are subgraphs of the Hasse diagrams of weak orders, which is to say, subgraphs of the transitive reductions of weak orders.

@PaulTanenbaum I don't understand how can I relate Savitch theorem with Hasse diagraph of weak orders? Would you elaborate more.

I’m not sure it is applicable. That’s why I said only that it “may” help. But reachability—a key notion in the Savitch context—would correspond to precisely the partial orders I refer to. And by the way, you say you want to do a Savithch-like thing, so would some other valid proof not be of interest to you?

@PaulTanenbaum Savitch theorem is first priority to me, if give you me another solution, I will try to translate your solution into Savitch.

Iterate over the vertices in the middle layer $V_{k/2}$.  For each vertex $v$, recursively compute the parity of the number of paths from $s$ to $v$ and from $v$ to $t$.  Combine the answers to determine the parity of the number of paths from $s$ through $v$ to $t$.  Finally sum over $v$ to get the result.  You can check that this takes $O((\log n)^2)$ space.

Would you be elaborate how you get (log n)^2?

@Adam Finch It's the same argument as in the proof of Savitch's theorem.
